# Why cannot a Reactive object in reactiveUI be serilized in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, reactiveui

When I tried to serialize a ReactiveObject from ReactiveUI, I found out that it is serialized to null data in the JSON text.

```
 public string Get()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Value, Formatting.Indented);
       
    }
```

This method returns a Text with null Properties.

The default options for the JSON Serialization is as bellow:

```
 private static void SetGlobalSettings()
    {
        var temp = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new StringEnumConverter()
            },
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
          
        };

        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => temp;
    }
```

Why cannot Reactive Objects be serializable?

The intended object:

```
 public class DataSettings :ReactiveObject, IDataSettings
{
    public DataSettings()
    {
        Model = new ModelParameter();
        VisualParameters = new VisualParameters();
        FiberParameters = new FiberParameter();
        App = new AppSetting();
        Optimization = new OptimizationSettings();
    }
    [Reactive] public ModelParameter Model { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public VisualParameters VisualParameters { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public FiberParameter FiberParameters { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public AppSetting App { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public OptimizationSettings Optimization { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataContractAttribute from Newtonsoft.Json.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataSettings : ReactiveObject, IDataSettings
{
    public DataSettings()
    {
        Model = new ModelParameter();
        VisualParameters = new VisualParameters();
        FiberParameters = new FiberParameter();
        App = new AppSetting();
        Optimization = new OptimizationSettings();
    }
    [DataMember][Reactive] public ModelParameter Model { get; set; }
    [DataMember][Reactive] public VisualParameters VisualParameters { get; set; }
    [DataMember][Reactive] public FiberParameter FiberParameters { get; set; }
    [DataMember][Reactive] public AppSetting App { get; set; }
    [DataMember][Reactive] public OptimizationSettings Optimization { get; set; }
}
```

more detail can be found here:
[Data Persistence](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-persistence/)